# Redux Toolkit w/ TS: what is the recommended approach for dispatching two consecutive async thunk actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I encountered this problem recently when I tried to use two different versions of an API. The logic is if `v2` of the API gives me a 404 error, then I would try `v1`, if no errors, I would use the results from `v2`

Here is my attempt: I created two separate async thunk actions for each version and then create a async thunk where I dispatch both actions.

```
export const getV2LoggingOptions = createAsyncThunk(
  "settings/getV2LoggingOptions",
  async () => {
    return sdkClient.getV2LoggingOptions().promise();
  }
);

export const getV1LoggingOptions = createAsyncThunk(
  "settings/getV1LoggingOptions",
  async () => {
    return sdkClient.getV1LoggingOptions().promise();
  }
);

export const getLoggingOptions = createAsyncThunk(
  "settings/getLoggingOptions",
  async (arg, thunkApi) => {
    let response = await thunkApi.dispatch(getV2LoggingOptions());
    if (response.error) {
      if (
        response.error.statusCode === "404"
      ) {
        response = await thunkApi.dispatch(getV1LoggingOptions());
      }

      throw response.error;
    }

    return response.payload;
  }
);
```

I think this approach works. but not sure if this is the best way of doing it. Right now there are a couple issues with this approach:

1. I don't know how I can properly type this response as in `let response = await thunkApi.dispatch(getV2LoggingOptions());`.
2. also, the `error` property inside of `response`(if `v2` call failed) doesn't contain a `statusCode` property. so I cannot read it. This is really confusing to me as to why it doesn't contain the `statusCode`

Then another approach would be just create one async thunk and call two versions inside directly

```
export const getLoggingOptions = createAsyncThunk(
  "settings/getLoggingOptions",

  async () => {
    let response;
    try {
      response = await sdkClient.getV2LoggingOptions().promise();
    } catch (error) {
      if (
        error.statusCode === "404"
      ) {
        response = await sdkClient.getV1LoggingOptions().promise();
      }
      throw error;
    }

    return response;
  }
);
```

It seems to be working too. but the issues are, still I am not sure how to type the `response` here.

The API does offer typing for its response. `GetV1LoggingOptionsResponse` and `GetV2LoggingOptionsResponse`. but I am not sure should I type the response as

```
let response: GetV1LoggingOptionsResponse | GetV2LoggingOptionsResponse
```

since then I can only read the overlapped part of these two types from the response.

also in the second approach `statusCode` is missing in the `error` that got caught in the `catch` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Since both apis have different return values, they should probably be different asyncThunks and you should handle their actions separately.
Also, you should do the error handling (including throwing) inside the respective asyncThunks, as that will lead to a `rejected` action that you can handle in the reducer.

Once you have those two asyncThunks, there is no reason for a third asyncThunk that will introduce it's own lifecycle actions that you really don't need as this is essentially just orchestration of the other two.

Write a normal thunk:

```js
const getLogginOptions = () => async (dispatch) => {
  let result = await dispatch(getV2LoggingOptions());
  if (getV2LoggingOptions.rejected.match(result)) {
    result =  await dispatch(getV1LoggingOptions());
  }
  return result;
}
```